# Significato di «alla destra/a destra di B c'è A»

Tags: meaning

Se, nella descrizione di una foto in cui sono presenti varie persone in posa (rivolte verso chi guarda), si dice che «alla destra di B c'è A», secondo voi si intende che nella foto osserviamo A a destra di B oppure che in quel momento B aveva alla propria destra A e quindi, per noi che guardiamo, A è a sinistra di B?

E cambia qualcosa se fosse stato detto «a destra di B c'è A»?

Comment: Nessuno che voglia contribuire altri 2 centesimi? Allo stato attuale la statistica è un po' bassina (una sola risposta...)

Answer (score 7):

Qui di seguito i miei 2 centesimi, come si direbbe in inglese...

«Alla destra di B c'è A» è terribilmente ambiguo. Non saprei dire se la maggior parte dei lettori prenderebbe la propria destra come riferimento in questo caso oppure no, ma a rigore è specificato che la destra è **di B**. Personalmente (ma non penso di fare testo) mi baserei, per disambiguare, sulla mia valutazione della precisione di chi scrive, oltre che su altri elementi.

«A destra di B c'è A» è più facilmente interpretabile nel primo modo (cioè nel sistema di riferimento del lettore), perché non c'è l'appartenenza di una cosa (la destra) a qualcuno, bensì la locuzione *a destra di*, che vale tanto quanto una singola preposizione. Ipotizzo quindi che la maggior parte dei lettori (me compreso) riferirebbe la destra alla propria persona, ma resta comunque un certo grado di ambiguità.

**Off topic**: Questa domanda mi fa venire in mente la questione del perché lo specchio scambia la sinistra con la destra ma non l'alto con il basso ;-)

Comment: Ottima risposta. Ma lo specchio non scambia la destra con la sinistra, scambia il davanti con il dietro!

Comment: @giomasce, non dico mica di no ;-)

Comment: Se ti metti in orizzontale a guardare lo specchio vedrai che scambia l'alto col basso, ma non (più) la destra con la sinistra.